# HTML - relationship between <a> vs <i>

Tags: html, css

My goal is to come up with a dropdown menu:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown', function() {
  var is_visible = $(this).find('.dropdown-content').is(":visible");
  $('.dropdown-content').toggle(false);

  if (is_visible == false){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-content').toggle(true);
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='dropdown'>
  <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Share</div>
    <div><a href="#" id="contact_delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i> Delete</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The question is, what is the semantic role of `<a>` tag in the dropdown-content item definition (provided I don't use its `href` attribute and use JavaScript to handle the click event)?

In other words: if I want to have a clickable icon, in which cases should I surround it with an `<a>` tag?

Comment: Generally, if you are going to a page or an area on a page, you should semantically wrap it in an `<a>` tag. If it's performing a function, you should wrap it in a `<button>` tag.

Comment: Take for example the case when I delete something by clicking on item. Should it be a button ?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I want to have a clickable icon, in which cases should I surround it with `<a>` tag?

The only case where you should wrap *anything* with an `<a>` tag is if [it's a link, or a placeholder for where a link could be](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#elementdef-a).

Otherwise, if you want to make something clickable, the appropriate element is [`<button type="button">`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#the-button-element).

The one exception to that is if you need to wrap anything that's not [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#kinds-of-content-phrasing-content), in which case I recommend using `<div role="button" tabindex="0>` with a `keydown` handler to trigger `click` events on <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and <kbd>Space</kbd>.

---

Additional notes about accessibility for icons, and icon fonts in general: If a network request fails and the icon font fails to load, your sighted users will find themselves in the same situation as your non-sighted users, where it's unclear as to what the button should do.

Generally speaking it's better to pair icons with textual labels, but if that's not possible, consider using an `<img>` element with `[alt]` text instead of the icon.

If that's not possible, at least add an [`[aria-label]`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-label) attribute.

Comment: thanks for detailed info. Could you take a minute to edit my jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/9npoexkL/) according to your coding style ?

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan, I'm sorry but I'm going to decline to do your work for you in this instance, however I will link you to [my recommended solution for dropdowns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38317768/497418). Note, that it *does* in fact use an `<a>` element, but it's actually making use of the `href` attribute to actively be a link. `<button type="button">` would have also been an appropriate replacement for the `<a>` element there.

Comment: I am not lazy :) Simply I can't figure out how you place the <i> inside button to look it really like an icon rather than a button. My code (http://jsfiddle.net/afe1o7qt/) ends up rendering a button :(

Comment: Or should I just surround <i> by a div? Looks like this is what you were talking about when mentioning `phrasing content` (I am not familiar with concept). Should I use `<div role="button" tabindex="0><i></i> My test</div>` in my case?